# mysql error 1064 create view syntax

Tags: mysql

I hate to have to ask people on the internet to syntax check a fairly simple MySQL view but I can't work out what's wrong with the syntax. I've tried everything I can think of and I just keep getting the 1064 error with no specific error message. The tblProjectClient table has Foreign keys to tblClient and tblProject. The purpose of this view is to get a complete list of Clients, with a column for how many projects they currently have associated with them. If i don't use the UNION part, I get an empty list when there are no ProjectClient records. Does anyone have any ideas? Cheers.

```
CREATE VIEW viewClientList AS (
select
  tblClient.strName      AS 'Name',
  (select
     count(*)
   from tblProjectClient
   where (tblProjectClient.intClientID = tblClient.intClientID)) AS 'Projects',
  tblClient.intClientID AS 'ID'
from (tblClient
   join tblProjectClient)) 
   union select 
tblClient.strName as 'Name',
   '0' as 'Projects',
   tblClient.intClientID as 'ID'
   from tblClient
   where (not(tblClient.intClientID 
   in(select intClientID as 'ID' from tblClient JOIN tblProjectClient)));
```

Answer (score 0):

Escape column names with ` not '.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help, but I found a simpler solution that works. For anyone else who wants to do something similar here's the query:

```
CREATE VIEW viewClientList AS (
SELECT
tblClient.strName      AS 'Name',
COUNT(tblProjectClient.intProjectID) AS 'Projects',
tblClient.intClientID AS 'ID'
FROM tblClient LEFT JOIN tblProjectClient ON tblClient.intClientID = tblProjectClient.intClientID);
```